# В чём разница между словами "местоположение", "месторасположение", "местонахождение"?

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика, синонимы, существительные, сложные-слова

В обыденной речи слова, указывающие на позицию чего-либо/кого-либо в пространстве, вида "**место**-что-то-там-**ение**" (местоПОЛОЖение, местоРАСПОЛОЖение, местоНАХОЖДение) употребляются порой как полные синонимы, но в чём между ними разница? В литературном произведении, думаю, разница будет иметь значение. Что более формально, что менее; по отношению к чему или кому употребимо то или иное слово?

Например, в формальной речи/докладе какого-нибудь военного, служителя закона, робота: "Место(...)ение цели выявлено", "Место(...)ение лица установлено", "Ведётся огонь по место(...)ению базы противника" — что лучше подойдёт?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамма.ру" ответила в общих чертах, что всё это синонимы и что автор текста волен сам разграничить их употребление.

*В толковом словаре русского языка перечисленные слова представлены как синонимы.
Очевидно, что чаще всего они встречаются в деловой и профессиональной речи, а следовательно, нужно принять во внимание традиции употребления этих слов в конкретных сферах, например юридической, административной, военной, научной. Допускаем, что в каком-либо тексте одно из слов, по мнению автора, может оказаться предпочтительным.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посмотреть значения слов **по словарю**, но носители языка и так должны уметь выбрать нужное слово, а по словарю они обычно **уточняют** его значение.

Поэтому попробуем сначала сориентироваться без словаря, так как смысл слова можно считать с его **морфемного состава**.

Итак, у нас три глагола: ***положить, расположить, находиться***. И три разных объекта: ***лицо, цель, база***.

Объекты различны по подвижности и по занимаемой территории (цель как точка или территория и база как территория). Подвижный объект обычно находят, для базы подойдет приставка РАС.  Ну а цель может быть разная, но будем считать ее точечной.

Тогда решение такое: ***Местоположение** цели выявлено. **Местонахождение** лица установлено.  Ведётся огонь **по месторасположению** базы противника.*

**Словарь** в качестве приложения (он, кстати, дает довольно общие сведения)

**МЕСТОПОЛОЖЕНИЕ**, -я; ср. чего. Географическое положение какого-л. пункта или участка земной поверхности. Найти м. города на карте. Прибрежное м. страны. // Расположение чего-л. на какой-л. территории. М. города в низине. Быть недовольным местоположением дома.

**МЕСТОРАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ**, -я; ср. чего. =Местонахождение. М. садоводства. Прийти в м. штаба.

**МЕСТОНАХОЖДЕНИЕ**, -я; ср. кого-чего. Пункт, место, где кто-, что-л. находится. М. полезных ископаемых. Определить м. подводной лодки. Сообщить о местонахождении альпинистов